# Convert bytes to hard drive factory (advertised) space

Tags: php

I pull the hard drive size from a computer and then use PHP to convert it to it's human readable size (E.G 750GB)

The problem is, the advertised space in hard drives is not the same as the actual size of the hard drive, but I want my PHP to display the advertised size.

This is my code:

```
function formatBytes($size, $precision = 0) {
    $base = log($size, 1024);
    $suffixes = array('', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');

    return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), $precision) . $suffixes[floor($base)];
}
```

This is code that I found here on Stack. If I supply this with bytes for a `128GB` (`128035676160 bytes`) hard drive, it actually displays `119GB`. The expected result is `128GB`. For a 1TB hard drive, the bytes are `1000204886016`, and the expected result is `1TB` or `1000GB`, but I actually get `931GB`.

A possible solution is to break the bytes string when the first `0` appears, and then I should have the expected result. `1` for 1tb, or `128` for 128GB. I'm just not sure if this will always work, and wanted a safer way to do this operation as it is important to my software.

I can't think of a logical way to do this, or even if it is possible. Any help with this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Hard drive manufacturers actually use the power of 1000 (instead of the power of 1024, which RAM and computers use) when they display the size of a hard drive. So simply try using 1000 and instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Wow I feel dumb now. Thank you, that worked!

Comment: Yeah, @MagnusEriksson is right. I was about to type up an answer with this, but that comment pretty much sums it up. See the [Wikipedia article on Byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Unit_multiples). However, I'm uncertain where the remaining difference (`128035676160` vs. `128000000000`) comes from.

Comment: @domdom Yeah I was curious about that as well, however, I don't think it matters for my current project.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson If you could create an answer that would be great, I think this could help future readers. I tried so many searches and couldn't find an answer to this.

Comment: 128035676160 is the _actual_ size of the drive in bytes.

Comment: So I assume they are a slight bit bigger to account for some meta data like file system information and the like?

Comment: I have no idea _why_ that is, just that it is...

Comment: Oh well, who cares about those few bytes. ;) Anyway, over at SuperUser there is another interesting question on the same original topic: [*Why are hard drives never as large as advertised?*](https://superuser.com/questions/504/why-are-hard-drives-never-as-large-as-advertised)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard drive manufacturers actually use the power of 1000 (instead of the power of 1024, which RAM and computers use) when they display the size of a hard drive in KB, MB, GB, TB etc. So simply try using 1000 and instead.

For a more in-depth answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Unit_multiples
(As @domdom referred to in his comment).

Comment: It is interesting to note that Windows (including Win 10) is doing this the wrong way, contributing to the common misconception and head scratching after plugging in a new drive (as advertised and reported size don't match up). Right-click any drive or file, select *Properties* and check the reported size. While they use the decimal units (KB, MB, GB, ...), they calculate the binary way. The values should actually read KiB, MiB, GiB and so on. All Linux distributions I've used are handling this correctly, see for example the [Ubuntu Units Policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy).

Comment: Two interesting articles on the topic: [For the Same File, Why Windows and Ubuntu Show Different Sizes?](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/for-the-same-file-why-windows-and-ubuntu-show-different-sizes/) and [Why Do Hard Drives Show the Wrong Capacity in Windows?](https://www.howtogeek.com/123268/windows-hard-drive-wrong-capacity/)